# Qlikview - OnActivateSheet doesn't work in WebView/server

Tags: webview, triggers, macros, server, qlikview

I create sheet1 with Sheet Event Triggers -> OnActivateSheet -> Clear all
and second sheet2 with button Actions -> Activate Sheet -> sheet1
but when press my button OnActivateSheet doesn't work in WebView or QlikView Server.

I've set up this in my server but still don't work.

[image]

These work perfectly fine in the desktop version. However when the document is opened via the server the triggers seem to stop working.
I also created button to reload data Actions -> External -> Reload but also doesn't work in WebView or QlikView Server.

Does anyone have an idea why this don't work in the server and how to resolve problem? I use QlikView 12.

Answer (score 0):

Button with `Reload` action will never work outside the desktop mode. If you want to do it you need to have a web server that trigger an EDX task and extension in your app that communicate with the web server. One example how this can be done you can find [here](https://qvextcalledxfromajax.codeplex.com/). *(This will reload the document for all users not only for the one which actually pressed the button)*

`OnActivateSheet` is triggered only when you navigate to the sheet (pressing the tab in the tabrow). If you are using buttons/actions to activate the sheet the action is not triggered. Not sure why Qlik made it to work like this.

Comment: How to create a EDX trigger action for reload on button the application in server machine. 
Please list the steps to follow, because I am new in QLikView and  don't understand this. I download example from link that you post and run example but what is next to do.
Thanks

Comment: You can read the quick documentation https://qvextcalledxfromajax.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Installation&referringTitle=Documentation
Basically there is a web service that runs in IIS and the extension is communicating with this web service. But first you need to set reload task in your QV Server. The web service will trigger this task. This is a bit old project. And its more or less proof of concept. I've tested it back then and it was working ok. Not guarantee that will work with the latest versions of QV

Comment: I use Qlikview version 12 and EDX trigger doesn't work in this version of QlikView

Comment: Need to test it with QV 12. Had a chat with my colleagues about this. They are using EDX a lot for their tasks. And they told me that they've tested EDX with QV 12 and all is working.

Comment: Are you sure your reload task is set to be triggered via external event?

Comment: No, I am not sure. I am new in QlikView and I have task to post app in access point and the app have button which when press reload data for all users that use app. 


This localy (desktop version) works fine but when put in server nothing is happening.